# XML elements are arranged alphabetically in installshield

Tags: xml, installshield

I'm using install shield to produce an msi but i have added an XML file in the XML files portion but after installing the package the XML node elements get sorted alphabetically avoiding the package to run successfully,
here are the XML file nodes after installing:

```
<applicationSettings>
...
</applicationSettings>
<configSections>
...
</configSections>
```

and here is the desired one:

```
<configSections>
...
</configSections>
<applicationSettings>
...
</applicationSettings>
```

Please help me,

thank you very much in advance

Answer (score 1):

Relying on the XML elements order is a bad idea. You never know how that order can be changed. Also, most setup authoring tools don't use a specific order. Some of them sort alphabetically, others use the row order inside the package.

I recommend modifying your application to read the XML elements as they come, regardless of order. This is what most applications do.

Comment: the problem that they come sorted alphabetically so when the application tries to execute it it didn't work how to solve this???

thanks

Comment: Like I recommended in my post, modify your application to accept any order.

Answer (score 0):

Installshield appears to do this, which means the use of configSections is not possible when creating an the config via installshield.

As for haggag87's comment, this isn't an application design issue, this is the .net framework complaining, not Cosmin's application.

See this KB article: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/307506

I have just tested and it is still a problem on .net 4.0